# Regex brackets and brackets next to eachother

Tags: c#, regex

I'm a regex novice and I cannot figure out how to match the following:

String example:

> "This is my string [something: something] and the string is very
>   pretty [something: something][a][b][c]."

At the moment I got a regex that matches all start and end square brackets. `\[([^]]*)\]`.

This yields the following

- [something: something]
- [something: something]
- [a]
- [b]
- [c]

I want to group standalone brackets and brackets which has brackets next to it.

The regex should group it like;

- [something: something]
- [something: something][a][b][c]

Anyone able to help?

Comment: special regex characters can be backslashed if you want to find those characters.  `[a-c]*` will find  `abc` but `\[a-c\]` will find `[a-c]`

Comment: To group you can use [groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group): `(?:\[[^\]]*\])+`

Comment: If you need the contents in between the square brackets, use `(?:\[([^]]*)])+` and access the CaptureCollection.

Comment: @bobblebubble that was exactly what i was looking for! Thanks alot!

Comment: @user3249398: Your regex contains a capturing group. Do you need to capture the contents in-between each `[...]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
((?:\[[^]]*\])+)
```

- The non-captured group `(?:\[[^]]*\])` matches `[`, then any number of characters upto `]` and then `]`
- The captured group `((?:\[[^]]*\])+)` matches one or more occurrence of the non-captured group

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uU4nM3/1)

Comment: Nice. I was thinking about doing lookaheads to not match a closing ] if it had a following [ and things like that. This is a much simpler solution than mine would have been. :)